# trying to combine multiple table for report in odoo, but it give me a blank error

Tags: csv, odoo, python-3.7, odoo-13

I am new around here, and I need some help
so, I am trying to make a report in odoo with [Base report CSV](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/report_csv/), in the table, I have 2 relational field, and I don't know how to combine those table, I tried combining the function from the module Base report CSV like below, but it give an error, a blank error which only make me confused, anyone got any idea how I could do this?

```
from odoo import models
import csv

class csvreport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.hr_timesheet.report'
    _inherit = 'report.report_csv.abstract'
    def generate_csv_report(self, writer, data, partners):
        writer.writeheader()
        for obj in partners:
            employee = self.env.cr.execute("""select hr_employee.name where hr_employee.id = %s;""", (obj.employee_id))
            task = self.env.cr.execute("""select project_task.name where project_task.id = %s;""", (obj.project_id))
            writer.writerow({
                'name': obj.name,
                'date': obj.date,
                'unit_amount': obj.unit_amount,
                'responsible': employee.fetchall(),
                'task': task.fetchall(),
            })

    def csv_report_options(self):
        res = super().csv_report_options()
        res['fieldnames'].append('name')
        res['fieldnames'].append('date')
        res['fieldnames'].append('unit_amount')
        res['fieldnames'].append('responsible')
        res['fieldnames'].append('task')
        res['delimiter'] = ';'
        res['quoting'] = csv.QUOTE_ALL
        return res
```

The Error : 
[Since i can't post picture, i'll just post a gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gz-4h9vXLYLg9iBtlWdx7RfjzTsmmwI7/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You should see the following error message in the error log:

```
ValueError: SQL query parameters should be a tuple, list or dict; ...
```

To fix that error pass query arguments in a tuple:

```
employee = self.env.cr.execute(query_str, (obj.employee_id.id, ))
```

You can't pass `obj.employee_id` (a record), because `psycopg2` can't adapt type `hr.employee`.

To get the employee name just use dot notation:

```
employee_name = obj.employee_id.name
```

The `from` clause is missing for both queries and you can't call `fetchall` on `employee` or `task` because [self.env.cr.execute](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) will return `None`, to fetch the result, use the cursor [fetch*()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#fetch) methods.

```
self.env.cr.fetchall()
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, it's working now. I usually code in PHP (codeigniter), so I don't have a clue of how odoo works.

Comment: [Building a Module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/es/developer/howtos/backend.html) tutorial is a good start in Odoo.